# Java - Calculate PI - Single vs Multi-Thread

Tags: java

I have no clue why but my single thread code to calculate PI is much faster than multi. I'm using 500 Million points and for multi-thread 16 cores. With single CPU is fine and multi-thread all 16 Cores are 100% but it's slower...

Any clue??

Single

```
    public static double monteCarloMethodSequencialMethod(long points) {
    long inCircle = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < points; i++) {

        double x = Math.random();
        double y = Math.random();

        if(x * x + y * y <= 1) inCircle++;
    }

    return 4.0 * inCircle / points;
}
```

> Sequencial Monte-Carlo estimated PI value : 3.141562496. Executed in 13432.927304 ms.

Multi-Thread

```
    public double calculatePI() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    double sum = 0;

    List<Future<Double>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nProcessors);

    for (long i = 0; i < points; i += points / nProcessors) {
        Future<Double> task = executor.submit(() -> {
            long inCircle = 0;
            double val = 0;

            for(long k = 0; k < points / nProcessors; k++) {
                double x = Math.random();
                double y = Math.random();

                if(x * x + y * y <= 1) inCircle++;
            }
            val = 4.0 * inCircle;

            return val;
        });

        tasks.add(task);
    }

    long pending = nProcessors;
    while(pending != 0) {
        for(Future<Double> future : tasks) {
            if(future.isDone()) {
                sum += future.get();
                pending--;
                System.out.println(pending + " task are still pending");
            }
        }
    }       

    executor.shutdown();

    return sum / points;
}
```

> Concurrent Monte-Carlo estimated PI value : 3.141666048. Executed in 116236.812471 ms.

Comment: Also if I run the multi thread with only one `nProcessors` it has the same time has the sequencial which makes sence. `Concurrent Monte-Carlo estimated PI value : 3.141584408. Executed in 13376.992822 ms.`

Comment: I am able to reproduce that. Maybe some expert will be able to explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, you make heavy use of random numbers. Note that `java.util.Random` is not ideal in such a situation, as it creates congestion between the threads. That is a known performance issue (source [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)):

> Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.

I would recommend to switch to [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) instead:

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()
```

Comment: Perfect. Works fine now :D

Comment: Very good. Didnt knew that part of documentation. I came to the same conclusion when I replaced radnoms with value incrementation which turnover the whole situation.